# How do I update sudo package version?

Tags: 18.04, sudo

With the news of the vulnerability found in sudo versions prior to 1.8.28, I am trying to upgrade to that version, but have had no luck. I did `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and sudo continues to be at the same version. Even tried `sudo apt-get upgrade sudo` and it says it's at the latest, which cannot be entirely true since 1.8.28 was released earlier today.

How does one typically go about updating packages using `apt-get` to latest versions?

Comment: Related: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283/367990) but security patches get usually backported to the specific version a release uses pretty quickly.

Comment: Please share the CVE number if you really worry.

Comment: Just came out today, See here, https://usn.ubuntu.com/4154-1/   I see the sudo update here in both 16.04 and 18.04.. If you don't see make sure bionic-updates and bionic-security are enabled in your sources.

Comment: With security issues, one typically goes about updating by ensuring you have the -security repository enabled. That's where the Ubuntu Security Team uploads to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is known as [CVE-2019-14287](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/CVE-2019-14287) and already fixed as backport.

All you need - is to run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

(but is more likely that `unattended-upgrades` was already installed all updates)

See USN https://usn.ubuntu.com/4154-1/ :

> [image: sudo]

and was indicated in changelog of [sudo *1.8.21p2-3ubuntu1.1*](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/1.8.21p2-3ubuntu1.1) for 18.04 LTS.

Comment: To add a bit of info to this answer, security fixes like this one are backported and applied to the application version currently in the repositories as the [Ubuntu repositories don't offer the latest version of packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283) after an OS has been released (To be precise, once the packages' version is frozen during development). For example, the `sudo` package in 14.04 is still version 1.8.9 as you can see in the screenshot, but it is actually patched to include the fix for the vulnerability.

Comment: "the packages' version is frozen during development" - How do I get the latest versions of things on linux, if they're not in the repositories?  I have to clone and compile everything?

Comment: @AdamBarnes It's hard to give justice to an answer to that question in a comment. I strongly recommend checking the answers to the question I linked in my previous comment. If none of them answers your question, you can always ask a new one!

Answer (score 4):

For me it was enough to run:

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `apt-cache policy sudo` and check versions (Installed: 1.8.16-0ubuntu1.5, Candidate: 1.8.16-0ubuntu1.8 = this version fixed problem)
3. `sudo apt-get install sudo`

And the package was updated and check that bug: `sudo -u#-1 whoami` no more works

Comment: Question for "+1"-voters - why do you think that this answer is an answer? The third command will fail with "`E: The update command takes no arguments`" error. So it should be edited to become correct. Otherwise it is bad and low-quality answer. We can not use it to get positive result. Also `apt-cache` do not require `sudo` rights. I'll recommend  @user1005724 to read  `man apt-get` and `man apt-cache` before posting answers for very serious topics about security.

Comment: 3. Should be either `sudo apt upgrade` to apply all available updates, or `sudo apt install sudo` or `sudo apt install --only-upgrade sudo` for only that specific upgrade. Right now, the suggested command does not work, as N0rbert correctly pointed out.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct Byte Commander, I have updated the answer. My bad. Thanks for pointing this out. The goal was to point out that it is enough to update just a single package to solve the problem. There are a lot of admins who cannot afford to upgrade whole system like a charm ... :-)